# How to read from SQLite database and then use within xml files

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite

I have a very primitive application which allows me to write questions and insert them into a database.
I now need to read from this database and use these questions within a "complete survey" class.
I want the question to be the main text on the page and then the multiple choice answers from the database to be displayed as 3 buttons which the user chooses from the answer the question. So therefor the button text must be the answers read from the database.

my database handler class:

```
package com.example.david.myview3;

/**
* Created by David on 23/03/2017.
*/

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class SurveyDataBaseAdapter {
static final String DATABASE_NAME = "survey.db";
static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final int NAME_COLUMN = 1;
// TODO: Create public field for each column in your table.
// SQL Statement to create a new database.
static final String DATABASE_CREATE1 = "create table " + "USER" +
        "( " + "ID" + " integer primary key autoincrement," + "ID    int,NAME text); ";
static final String DATABASE_CREATE2 = "create table " + "QUESTION" +
        "( " + "ID2" + " integer primary key autoincrement," + "QUESTION  text,ANSWER1 text, ANSWER2 text, ANSWER3 text);  ";
static final String DATABASE_CREATE3 = "create table " + "RESPONSE" +
        "( " + "ID3" + " integer primary key autoincrement," + "ID  int,QUESTION text, ANSWER int);  ";

// Variable to hold the database instance
public SQLiteDatabase db;
// Context of the application using the database.
private final Context context;
// Database open/upgrade helper
private DataBaseHelper dbHelper;

public SurveyDataBaseAdapter(Context _context) {
    context = _context;
    dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

public SurveyDataBaseAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    db.close();
}

public SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseInstance() {
    return db;
}

public void insertQuestion(String question, String answerOne, String answerTwo, String answerThree) {
    ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
    // Assign values for each row.
    newValues.put("QUESTION", question);
    newValues.put("ANSWER1", answerOne);
    newValues.put("ANSWER2", answerTwo);
    newValues.put("ANSWER3", answerThree);
    // Insert the row into your table
    db.insert("QUESTION", null, newValues);
    ///Toast.makeText(context, "Reminder Is Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}



}
```

and how my complete survey class currently looks, i've established the buttons and desired layout.

```
package com.example.david.myview3;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Button;


public class CompleteSurveyActivity extends DashBoardAppActivity
{

Button btnAnswer1, btnAnswer2, btnAnswer3;
SurveyDataBaseAdapter SurveyDataBaseAdapter;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView (R.layout.message);

  //get refs of buttons
    btnAnswer1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAnswer1);
    btnAnswer2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAnswer2);
    btnAnswer3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAnswer3);

   // TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.title_text);
   // if (tv != null)
   // {
   //     tv.setText(getTitle());
  //  }
}




}
```

So basically my queries are:

1) How can i read the database so i can display the question inserted at the top of the complete survey page.
2) How can i read the database to display the multiple choice answers on the  buttons.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get question and answers from database using [query()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method of sqlite.

For example.

Change your `SQLiteDatabase` object and `getDatabaseInstance()` method type  to static like below.

```
// Variable to hold the database instance
public static SQLiteDatabase db;

public static SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseInstance() {
    return db;
}
```

Then add below function into your `CompleteSurveyActivity` class.

```
public void getQuestionAnswers() {
    String question, answer1, answer2, answer3; 

    Cursor cursor = SurveyDataBaseAdapter.getDatabaseInstance().query("QUESTION", null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {

            cursor.moveToLast(); // To get last inserted record

            String question = cursor.getString(1);
            String answer1 = cursor.getString(2);
            String answer2 = cursor.getString(3);
            String answer3 = cursor.getString(4);            
    }

    tv.setText(question);
    btnAnswer1.setText(answer1);
    btnAnswer2.setText(answer2);
    btnAnswer3.setText(answer3);
}
```

Comment: where would i place this code though? within my complete survey class or the database helper?

Comment: @Dave95 Check my updated answer. This is just example code. You need to made changes in it according to your requirements.

Comment: I've tweaked a lot and got it working with help from your answer, thankyou Priyank.